# foreign key references invalid table. BUT WHY

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE Bookings
(
    BookingID CHAR(10) CONSTRAINT pkBookinglD PRIMARY KEY,
    BookingName CHAR(30), 
    Price INT,
    Catergory CHAR(30),

    RoomID CHAR(10) 
        CONSTRAINT fkRoomID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Rooms(RoomID)
)
```

Error message:

> Foreign key `fkRoomID` references invalid table `Rooms`.

How do I fix this? I have the table 'Rooms' but it keeps saying invalid table.

This is my rooms table

```
CREATE TABLE Rooms
(
    RoomID CHAR(10) CONSTRAINT pkRoomlD PRIMARY KEY,
    RoomType CHAR(30), 
    Price INT, 
    FloorNumber INT
)
```

Comment: What schema is the `Rooms` table in?

Answer (score 4):

If you are creating the tables using single script, script for creating Rooms table should be on top and then for table 'Bookings'. Another option is add all the tables with Primary key at first, then `Alter table` and add foreign key constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE Bookings
    ADD CONSTRAINT fkRoomID FOREIGN KEY(RoomID) REFERENCES Rooms(RoomID)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I restarted MS SQL and the error just disappeared.

Comment: Strange. I did the same. Restarted SSMS. And, it just worked!

Comment: Sadly, mine didn't 

Answer (score 1):

Check that the correct database is selected in the "Available databases" drop-down control.